# React-native navigation, hide bottom tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
      >
        <Tab.Screen
           name="Галерея" component={Gallery}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          }
        }}
           name="Избранное" component={Favorites}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
           name="{item}" component={PhotoScreen}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

And i dont wanna show last bottom tab on the bottom menu
How can i hide it?
Maybe i need to create one more Stack?
or i can hide it with some options?

[image: app screen]

Comment: i dont wanna show tab which is called {item}

Comment: You can hide whole tabbar for some specific screens. If you want to hide just single tab in tabbar for specific screen then you have to make another tab navigator. [click link for more information about hiding tab bar in specific screens]{https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/}